# Error while getting data from Service bus queue in azure

Tags: azure

I am working on a `POC` for processing large data from client to server using azure as a platform.

In my initial `POC` outcome , I am able to send the data to service bus queue.

But problem is when i am getting the data from service bus queue.

Technology stack i am using as below :-

1. Spring
2. Rest full web service
3. cxf framework
4. Azure api for get and put message.

**Below is the error i am getting :-**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getResponseDate(ClientResponse.java:669)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.receiveMessage(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:277)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.receiveQueueMessage(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.receiveQueueMessage(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:137)
    at com.toyota.tme.services.impl.messageQueueImpl.getMessage(messageQueueImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
243178483 [qtp670576685-43] INFO  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor  - Outbound Message
```

**Code i am using as below :-**

```
public Response getMessage() throws Exception {

    ServiceBusConfig serviceBusConfig = new ServiceBusConfig();
    ServiceBusContract serviceBusContract = serviceBusConfig.serviceBusContract();
    LOGGER.info("serviceBusContract: " + serviceBusContract);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
        LOGGER.info("opts: " + opts);
        opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
        LOGGER.info(" after opts: " + opts);
        while (true) {
            ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM =
                    serviceBusContract.receiveQueueMessage("dev1-queue", opts);
            LOGGER.info("resultQM: " + resultQM);
            BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue();
            LOGGER.info("message: " + message);
            if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null) {
                LOGGER.info("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
                // Display the queue message.
                LOGGER.info("From queue: ");
                byte[] b = new byte[200];
                String s = null;
                int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                while (-1 != numRead) {
                    s = new String(b);
                    s = s.trim();
                    LOGGER.info(s);
                    stringBuffer.append(s);
                    numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Finishing up - no more messages.");
                break;
                // Added to handle no more messages.
                // Could instead wait for more messages to be added.
            }
        }
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        LOGGER.info("ServiceException encountered: ");
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.exit(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Generic exception encountered: ");
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to receive a message when one is not ready.  I'm not familiar with how the serviceBusContract can be used for listening asynchronously for messages from queues.

I've been able to send and receive messages to/from Queue using the Apache Qpid JMS Client Library.  This is the recommended approach for Java messaging against service bus.  What Apache Qpid does is provide a JMS Layer over the AMQP endpoints that is serviced by Service Bus.  I have found that, for Queues, interacting with Service Bus is no different from other JMS Providers.

I've used Spring-JMS (using Spring boot... but the JMS should work in plain Spring) along with AMQP to handle messages via queues.  You can find more specific details of how I did this here

http://ramblingstechnical.blogspot.in/p/using-azure-service-bus-with-spring-jms.html

Comment: @SatishBhuria You can see the full code on GitHub: https://github.com/hildo/azureSamples